# Javascript fail to execute function - onsubmit and action

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am creating a page that is only javascript and html. I have 2 problems.

1. When it calls the function inputs() in this form, it fails at the first time and success on the next submissions.

   `<div id="container">
       <form onsubmit="inputs()" action="#">
           Variables: <input type="number" id="vars" size="1" required/> 
           Constraints: <input type="number" id="cons" size="1" required/> 
           <input type="submit" value="Submit">
       </form>
   </div>`

I wasnt able to solve this but I skipped it because it still proceeds to the inputs() the next submissions.

But in my inputs(), i created a form dynamically.  The form is created as this:

```
   var form = document.createElement("form");
   form.setAttribute("action","#");
   form.setAttribute("onsubmit","solve()");
```

2. Now, when I submit the dynamically created form, the problem is it goes back to the first set of form. solve() was not called.

Why is it? What should be edited?

Thanks for the help in advance.

solve() has these lines of codes. It's just a test if it will successfully go into it but it fails. This just deletes all the elements.

```
    var container = document.getElementById("container");
    while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
        container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
    }
```

Comment: I think form.setAttribute("onsubmit","solve()"); should be form.setAttribute("onsubmit",solve());, passing function as second parameter, not string.

Comment: it didnt work. errors like: 
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null...
occured

Comment: could you add code of solve() function too?

Comment: added solve() @Rasalom

Comment: well, I thought error might occur there, but looks like it's not. Could you create a fiddle that reproduces your problem?

Comment: they just accept post not this kind of code.. i can give you the whole code if you want. @Rasalom

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what you're trying to achieve, could you post the code and perhaps consider explaining what you are trying to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
form.setAttribute("onsubmit","solve()");
```

isn't doing what you think it does. If it was in the actual html it would work but not now. What it does is just make the attribute appear in the console. The event handler isn't actually being set.

Instead do it via `onsubmit` property or `addEventListener`

```
form.onsubmit = solve; // now it must work
```

Comment: onsubmit didnt turn into blue text like other and the same problem occurs

Answer (score 0):

Try return false at the end of the function solve. this should work to show but would not perform action. Also add "return solve()" instead of "solve()".